# not working event change on select for multiple classname

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page that multiple selects.

1. When the option of some of them is clicked (value=0), a text box should be opened in order for the user to write her description in it.
2. I want the same text box to be closed when the user clicks on any part of the page except the text box.
3. I want the text box to close automatically when the user goes to the before or next selector.

Event click not working on the options of select.
but this code not working.

If you have a suggestion for solving this problem, thank you for letting me know

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
function changeFunc(){
  var selectBox = document.querySelectorAll(".selectBox");
  var selectedValue = selectBox.value;
  var description = document.querySelectorAll('.description');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < selectBox.length; i++) {
      selectBox[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      if(selectedValue == '0'){
          selectBox[i].classList.add('active');
          description[i].classList.add('show');
                    
          window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
              var desText = document.querySelector('.description.show');
              if (event.target !== desText) {
                  description.classList.remove('show');                            
              }
          });
            
      }else{
           selectBox[i].classList.remove('active');
           description[i].classList.remove('show');           
      }
  })
            
 }        
}
```

```css
select{
    width: 70%;
    border:1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, .5);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

select.active{
    background: yellow;
    color: white;
}

.description{
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #e6eef7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13.75%;
    top: 85%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;   
}

.line-form .description.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="example1">example1</label>
    <select class="selectBox"  name="whois" id="example1" required             onchange="changeFunc();">
         <option value="1" >No</option>
         <optgroup label="Yes">
            <option value="0">Explain more for yes</option>
          </optgroup>                                                     </select>
    <textarea class="description" name="example1"  cols="50"            rows="3">       </textarea>
</div>


<div>
    <label for="example2">example2</label>
    <select class="selectBox"  name="whois" id="example2" required             onchange="changeFunc();">
         <option value="1" >No</option>
         <optgroup label="Yes">
            <option value="0">Explain more for yes</option>
          </optgroup>                                                     </select>
    <textarea class="description" name="example2"  cols="50"            rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="example3">example3</label>
    <select class="selectBox"  name="whois" id="example3" required             onchange="changeFunc();">
         <option value="1" >No</option>
         <optgroup label="Yes">
            <option value="0">Explain more for yes</option>
          </optgroup>                                                     </select>
    <textarea class="description" name="example3"  cols="50"            rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes to your code and added a "show" class to css.

When "YES" is selected from the options menu, which has the value = 0, "textarea" is displayed. When you click on another menu with options or anywhere else "textarea" is hidden.

When clicked, the script places on the parent packaging DIV element class ".selected". When clicking on an element the script looks for the closest element with this class. In this case it is the parent element ... if it does not have the active class "textarea" it will be hidden.

**Step-by-step description:**

1. Get all elements with class .selectBox
2. Add listner for "click" and "change" events on all elements with class .selectBox. This events call the function "changeFunc()".
3. Add listner on the window -> if user click anywhere the script search for closest element with class .selected (In this case this must be a parent element). If it is not, it means that it has been clicked outside the selected element and the function that removes the classes of the active element "removeClasses()" should be called.
4. The function "changeFunc()" First removes activity classes from all items by calling the function "removeClasses()". Then gets as an argument which is the clicked element. And checks if its value is equal to "0" and if it sets the activity classes.
5. The function "removeClasses()" removes activity classes from all items

```js
var selectBox = document.querySelectorAll(".selectBox");

selectBox.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('change', function () {
        changeFunc(this);
    });

    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        changeFunc(this);
    });
});

window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var closest = event.target.closest('.selected');
    if (!closest) {
        removeClasses();
    }
});

function changeFunc(x) {
    removeClasses();

    if (x.value === '0') {
        x.classList.add('active');
        x.classList.add('show');
        x.parentNode.querySelector('.description').classList.add('show');
        x.closest('div').classList.add('selected');
    }
}

function removeClasses() {
    selectBox.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove('active');
        el.classList.remove('show');
        el.parentNode.querySelector('.description').classList.remove('show');
        el.closest('div').classList.remove('selected');
    });
}
```

```css
select {
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(112, 112, 112, .5);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

select.active {
    background: yellow;
    color: white;
}

.description {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #e6eef7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13.75%;
    top: 85%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.line-form .description.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="example1">example1</label>
    <select class="selectBox" name="whois" id="example1" required>
        <option value="1">No</option>
        <optgroup label="Yes">
            <option value="0">Explain more for yes</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <textarea class="description" name="example1" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="example2">example2</label>
    <select class="selectBox" name="whois" id="example2" required>
        <option value="1">No</option>
        <optgroup label="Yes">
            <option value="0">Explain more for yes</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <textarea class="description" name="example2" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="example3">example3</label>
    <select class="selectBox" name="whois" id="example3" required>
        <option value="1">No</option>
        <optgroup label="Yes">
            <option value="0">Explain more for yes</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <textarea class="description" name="example3" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @haniye If I need to write in detail how my example works, I will!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The problem is in
`var selectedValue = selectBox.value;`
selectBox is a collection of nodes, so You cannot get direct value from there. You need to loop through.
In your loop you need to get selected value using `selectBox[i].value`

And 1 more problem I can see, you are adding click event listener to the window, in the loop
It is not performant. You should pull this out from the loop

Comment: hello my friend. I did this but not worked.

Comment: @haniye What do you mean by did not work? What exactly did not work? Could you post your updated code again. Maybe you are doing something wrong/differently